# Why doesn't pstricks allow for my images to show?

Tags: graphics, pstricks

I have a simple file with a simple an figure I want to display on top but it's not showing. Instead, I just get this file:

> Latex Error: ./Mateus_010514.tex:17 LaTeX Error: File `justa' not
>   found.

This one figure doesn't compile, even though it should! And if I remove the packages, it does just fine.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]  \centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{justa}  \caption{Waveforms for
[hustatwa] and [hustatawa]}  \label{fig:justa} \end{figure}
```

I guess it's easier just to show you what I mean:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} %\documentclass{minimal} \usepackage{pstricks} \usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pagestyle{empty} \begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture} %{\usebox{\test}}; %\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{figure}[htbp]  \centering  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{justa}  \caption{Waveforms for [hustatwa] and [hustatawa]}  \label{fig:justa} \end{figure}

\color{white} %\color{black} % activate to see bounding box \fboxsep=0pt   
        % this figure is 50mm by 50mm
        \newsavebox{\gaussians}
        \savebox{\gaussians}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussianss}
        \savebox{\gaussianss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.3,1.5);
        \draw (-0.27,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.3,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.45);
        \draw (-0.2,0.45) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussiansss}
        \savebox{\gaussiansss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.65,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.4,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (0.5,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (1.8,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (2.4,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\oneline}
        \savebox{\oneline}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \psset{unit=1mm}
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %\tikz\draw (1,1) node{$\sigma$} -- (2,2) node{B};
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (0.7,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (2.3,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (3.75,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (5.2,0) node {\usebox{\oneline}};
        \draw (6.35,0) node {\usebox{\gaussianss}};
        \draw (9.5,0) node {\usebox{\gaussiansss}};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{picture}(100,100)
        \color{black} % for text 
        \put(-3,93){\Large{/mun}(a)}
        \put(52,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(68,93){\Large{t'(a)}}
        \put(95,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(110,93){\Large{k(a)}}
        \put(137,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(153,93){\Large{t}}
        \put(165,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(183,93){\Large{t(i)/}} 
        \put(232,93){\Large{[mun + t'+k+t+t]}} 
        \end{picture}
        %\begin{tikzpicture} 
        %\psset{unit=1mm}
        %\color{black} % for text
        %\draw (-4.4,1.4) node{/mun};
        %%\draw node{/mun(a) + t'(a) + k(a) + t + t(i)/};
        %%\draw (7.6,0) node{[mun + t' + k + t + t]};
        %\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What type of file is `justa`? PNG? JPEG? PDF? EPS? PS? Only the last two would work with LaTeX.

Comment: Do you have a file named `justa.eps`, especially in the directory where you are trying to compile your document. The error message just says,that there is no such file

Comment: What has your example to do with PSTricks? There is no such code?

Comment: "justa" is PNG -- the thing is, it compiles fine without this package, even if it isn't EPS or PS.

Comment: Without PSTricks the file doesn't compile correctly.

Comment: Compiling your MWE I get this error: "\begin{document} ended by \end{tikzpicture}. \end{tikzpicture}". Can you please clean up your MWE?

Comment: @mateuz: telling truth, I think mix TikZ and PSTricks as you did is not a good idea. For example, in first `\gaussians` box, you set `\psset{unit=1mm}` within a `tikzpicture`: it's hard to imagine the reason.

Comment: I also suggest you to use pst-asr if you need to represent syllabic structure. pst-asr is based on pstricks and I used it successfully together with tikz.

Answer (score 3):

this one runs fine (except the image, which I replaced by `tigereps|pdf`) with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. If your image isn't found then it is not in your documents directory or has not the valid extension (eps for `latex`or `pdf` for `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]  
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=3cm]{tiger}  
\caption{Waveforms for [hustatwa] and [hustatawa]}  \label{fig:justa} 
\end{figure}

\color{white} %\color{black} % activate to see bounding box \fboxsep=0pt   
        % this figure is 50mm by 50mm
        \newsavebox{\gaussians}
        \savebox{\gaussians}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussianss}
        \savebox{\gaussianss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.3,1.5);
        \draw (-0.27,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.3,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.45);
        \draw (-0.2,0.45) -- (-0.6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\gaussiansss}
        \savebox{\gaussiansss}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.2,0.5);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.65,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (-0.4,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (0.5,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (1.8,0);
        \draw (-0.2,0.5) -- (2.4,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \newsavebox{\oneline}
        \savebox{\oneline}{
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \color{black} % for text
        \draw (-1,0) -- (-0.5,1.5);
        \draw (-0.47,1.6) node{$\sigma$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        %\tikz\draw (1,1) node{$\sigma$} -- (2,2) node{B};
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (0.7,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (2.3,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (3.75,0) node {\usebox{\gaussians}};
        \draw (5.2,0) node {\usebox{\oneline}};
        \draw (6.35,0) node {\usebox{\gaussianss}};
        \draw (9.5,0) node {\usebox{\gaussiansss}};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{picture}(100,100)
        \color{black} % for text 
        \put(-3,93){\Large{/mun}(a)}
        \put(52,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(68,93){\Large{t'(a)}}
        \put(95,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(110,93){\Large{k(a)}}
        \put(137,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(153,93){\Large{t}}
        \put(165,93){\Large{+}}
        \put(183,93){\Large{t(i)/}} 
        \put(232,93){\Large{[mun + t'+k+t+t]}} 
        \end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I'm getting an undefined control sequence on line 37: i.e. the first "}" on a line of its own...  "Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

Including: justa.png
Latex Error: ./Mateus_010514.tex:37 Undefined control sequence."

Comment: provide your complete logfile for a download.

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2013.9.28)  3 MAY 2014 14:07
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Mateus_010514.tex
(./Mateus_010514.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19

Comment: that is only the beginning of the logfile.

Comment: indeed. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ORHUPor1y5iRxy_kZXYJQKuP5b7dzaWLHQ94Obevyac/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you have an old version of tikZ. You should update it.

Comment: How do I update tikZ? I didn't even install the package in the first place. It seems to be part of my TexMate..

Comment: I do not know `texmate`. However, you have TeXLive2013 running so you must be able to update it with `tlmgr --all --self update`